# class not declared although it is declared

Tags: c++, class, static, declaration

When I call the static method ClassA::it() in the method *conn* I get a compiler error.

```
#ifndef CLASSA
#define CLASSA

#include "ClassB.h"

namespace name {

class ClassA
{
public:
    static ClassA& it()
    {
        static ClassA c;
        return c;
    }

    [...]
};

}
#endif
```

-

```
#ifndef CLASSB
#define CLASSB

#include "ClassA.h"

namespace name {

class ClassB
{
public:
    static Handle conn()
    {
        return getHandle(ClassA::it().str());
    }
};

}

#endif
```

I get an compiler error which says that in the method *conn()* ClassA is not declared. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: The compiler has to parse one of those classes before the other one. It can't parse two classes simultaneously to resolve circular dependencies.

Comment: Move the definition of `conn` out of the header.

Comment: check out also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c